# TypeScript variable works at runtime but breaks during compile - scoping

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to reference a variable inside a TypeScript function that breaks compile but works fine at run time. This line breaks the compile:

```
console.log( EXP_SETTINGS.site.userInterface.showPostbackStatusDelay );
```

[image]

The reason I know it works at runtime is because I did the following:

1. Commented out the offending line.
2. Did a compile in VS2015 Pro - success.
3. Found js file generated by TS compile, which is named JSUI.js.
4. Inserted the offending line in the precise corresponding place, saved.
5. Ran my web page in Chrome - no errors - correct value is emitted to console.

So...clearly the variable I need is available and in global scope, yet TS blows up during compile. How can I solve this?

Comment: Where does the variable come from? It sounds like you need to add typings for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sure that variable is available to you, you can just declare it somewhere (at the base level) in your file:

```
declare const EXP_SETTINGS: any; // Replace any with appropriate type
```

This will allow you to reference it without typescript complaining. If you have a more specific type for it, I would recommend using that instead of `any`.

---

Or, if you're only using the `EXP_SETTINGS` variable in one place, or you don't want to include a type for it, you can just manually silence the compiler with a ts-ignore comment:

```
// @ts-ignore
console.log( EXP_SETTINGS.site... );
```

Comment: Must be at the base level, so not within any function/class/etc, but right at the file's root level.

Comment: Also, if you only use that variable in one place, adding a comment `// @ts-ignore` right above the call to `console.log` might be another good option.